# The minimum amount of tries for a matching game?

Tags: probability

The game, match it up, where you've got 20 cards and each card has another to match up to which is the same, i was wondering, is there a least amount of tries you can complete this game in or is it just luck?

Comment: Could you explain the rules and playing mechanism a little more clearly. For example are there ten distinct pairs. Do you take a pair of cards or do you see the first card before you choose the next one? At the moment your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Maybe https://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/analysis-of-the-memory-game/ will be of interest, or http://www.math.kth.se/xComb/x1.pdf or https://www.researchgate.net/publication/27405488_A_Mathematical_Note_of_Card_Games_III_on_Optimal_Strategies_in_the_Concentration_Game

Comment: Yes you have a look at one card first then the next one and the strategy to getting the least tries would be to remember where each one was that you originally picked. Also , for example there is a cat, tiger, dog, elephant (10 animals ) of which you need to match up. I have realised that it is quite simple because if your lucky you could get them all in your first try. So am i right by answering my own question by saying the least amount of tries is 10?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer you found in a comment is correct; the minimal amount of tries is $10$, which completes the game if you get every try right. The probability for this is

$$
\frac1{19}\cdot\frac1{17}\cdot\frac1{15}\cdot\frac1{13}\cdot\frac1{11}\cdot\frac19\cdot\frac17\cdot\frac15\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac11=\frac1{654729075}\approx1.5\cdot10^{-9}\;.
$$